# How can one get sparklyr::spark_apply() to spawn more than one worker?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I'm messing about with `{sparklyr}` in a local deployment, i.e. just the one box and I let sparklyr launch everything.  It seems that in local deployment only one executor is generated that is allowed to use all of the cores of the machine.  When I go into a `spark_apply()` (using a `group_by` arg with more than one value), I see only one core is being utilized by one Rscript `--slave`.  Is this just a limitation of Spark, i.e. one Rscript per executor, or is there some way to get `{sparklyr}` to spread the work out across more workers?  Are any of my above assumptions incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

This might come a bit late. But anyways:

You can start multiple workers on one machine by first setting

```
SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=2
```

followed by running

```
$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-master.sh
$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-slave.sh spark://hostname:7077 --cores 2
```

This should give you two local workers, each with 2 cores. Then you can go on and launch your sparklyr driver from R

```
cfg <- spark_config()
sc <- spark_connect(master = "spark://hostname:7077", config = cfg)
```

Now before running `spark_apply()`, make sure you have more partitions than cores, perhaps by calling `sdf_repartition()`. For me, on a 4 core machine (2 workers with 2 cores each) and an SDF consisting of 4 (or more) partitions, `spark_apply()` spawns 4 R sessions.

I do realize that this is not exactly what you asked for in that you're not using a sparklyr-installed spark instance. But you really just have to download a [spark release](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) and point $SPARK_HOME to the place you downloaded spark to in order to make this work.